# Trying to vary the tolerance of odeint but getting "Illegal input detected" and "Infinite loop"

Tags: python, odeint

I'm given the following differential equation y'' + a y' − y + b y^3 = c cos(kx) with initial conditions y(0) = y'(0) = 0 and parameter values a = 0.05, b = k = 1 and c = 0.5.

Now, what I'm trying to do is reduce the solver’s relative tolerance until the change in the numerical solution y(t) from the previous iteration is less than 10^−8 at x = x_max.

Here is my code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import brent
import numpy as np

def de( Y, t ): # de as an array
    a = 0.05    # parameters
    b = 1.0
    c = 0.5
    k = 1.0
    return np.array([Y[1], Y[0] - a*Y[1] - b*(Y[0])**3 - c*np.cos(k*t)])

def Ydiff(h, *args): # calculates difference between the solution Y1
    de = args[0]     # (with default relative error) and Y2 (with new 
    t  = args[1]     # relative error)
    y0 = args[2]
    Y1 = args[3]
    Y2 = odeint( de, y0, t, full_output=0, rtol=h)
    return np.linalg.norm(Y1[-1,0] - Y2[-1,0])    # linalg.norm isn't 
                                                  # necessary here
t  = np.linspace( 0, 100, 10000 )
y0 = np.array([ 0., 0. ])         # initial conditions [y(0),y'(0)]
Y1  = odeint( de, y0, t, full_output=0)
hmin = brent(Ydiff, args=(de,t,y0,Y1), brack=(0,1),full_output=False)

print Ydiff(hmin,de,t,y0,Y1)
```

and I'm getting the output:

```
lsoda--  rtol(i1) is r1 .lt. 0.0        
     In above message,  I1 =         1
     In above message,  R1 = -0.1618034000000E+01
Illegal input detected (internal error).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
```

Repeats with different R1 values...

```
lsoda--  run aborted.. apparent infinite loop
```

I don't understand why I'm getting "Illegal input detected" and the "apparent infinite loop". The latter is new, I'm not sure why that's happening.

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. I'm sorry about the format. I'm new to this and I don't know how to change it in order to make the problem look nice.

-EDIT-

I tried the suggested "full_output = 1" and changed the 5th line of Ydiff to

```
    Y2,p = odeint( de, y0, t, full_output=1,rtol=h)
    print p
    print
```

and I would get something like

```
{'nfe': array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 'nje': array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 'tolsf': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'nqu': array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 'lenrw': 52, 'tcur': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'hu': array([ -4.10454254e+77,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
     0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]), 'imxer': -1, 'leniw': 22, 'tsw': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'message': 'Illegal input detected (internal error).', 'nst': array([          0, -1217644544,   166928456, ...,        2133,
          2133,        2133]), 'mused': array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])}
```

or

```
{'nfe': array([   7,    9,   11, ..., 4547, 4547, 4547]), 'nje': array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 12, 12, 12]), 'tolsf': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'nqu': array([2, 2, 2, ..., 7, 7, 7]), 'lenrw': 52, 'tcur': array([  1.37153782e-02,   2.74214740e-02,   4.11275699e-02, ...,
     1.00011148e+02,   1.00011148e+02,   1.00011148e+02]), 'hu': array([ 0.0137061 ,  0.0137061 ,  0.0137061 , ...,  0.07718142,
    0.07718142,  0.07718142]), 'imxer': -1, 'leniw': 22, 'tsw': array([  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,  76.44146089,
    76.44146089,  76.44146089]), 'message': 'Integration successful.', 'nst': array([   3,    4,    5, ..., 2185, 2185, 2185]), 'mused': array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1])}
```

It's very odd. Today I didn't get an infinite loop error but I still get these messages. To see what's happening, I again edited that same line to:

```
    if p['message'] != 'Integration successful.':
    print '=======================\nkey \t 2-norm\n'
    for k in p.keys():
        if type(p[k]) == np.ndarray:
            if np.linalg.norm(p[k]) == 0.:
                print k,'\t ',np.linalg.norm(p[k],2)
            if np.linalg.norm(p[k]) == np.inf:
                print k,'\t ',np.linalg.norm(p[k],2)
            if np.linalg.norm(p[k]) == np.nan:
                print k,'\t ',np.linalg.norm(p[k],2)
    print '\n'
```

I've gotten as the output (besides the one occurrence of 'nje' being 0):

```
lsoda--  rtol(i1) is r1 .lt. 0.0        
    In above message,  I1 =         1
    In above message,  R1 = -0.7482574658091E-07
Illegal input detected (internal error).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
=======================
key      2-norm

tolsf     0.0
tcur      0.0
hu        0.0
tsw       0.0
```

I wonder how this can fixed if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `full_output` to `1` in  `Y2 = odeint( de, y0, t, full_output=1, rtol=h)` as suggested you will see the exact error:

```
 line 55, in Ydiff
return np.linalg.norm(Y1[-1,0] - Y2[-1,0])    # linalg.norm isn't
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

If you `print( type(Y2))`, you will see it is a tuple not an array. It is in fact a tuple of arrays:

```
(array([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -2.50008335e-05,  -4.99925000e-03],
       [ -9.99866688e-05,  -9.99600058e-03],
       ..., 
       [ -1.34944031e+00,  -1.27522994e+00],
       [ -1.36215569e+00,  -1.26750159e+00],
       [ -1.37479105e+00,  -1.25922413e+00]]), {'nfe': array([  29,   29,   31, ..., 4801, 4803, 4803], dtype=int32), 'nje': array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32), 'tolsf': array([  1.27797787e-316,   1.27797787e-316,   1.27797787e-316, ...,
         1.27797787e-316,   1.27797787e-316,   1.27797787e-316]), 'nqu': array([3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7], dtype=int32), 'lenrw': 52, 'tcur': array([  2.15045290e-02,   2.15045290e-02,   3.64071805e-02, ...,
         9.99873247e+01,   1.00033487e+02,   1.00033487e+02]), 'hu': array([ 0.01490265,  0.01490265,  0.01490265, ...,  0.04616208,
        0.04616208,  0.04616208]), 'imxer': -1, 'leniw': 22, 'tsw': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'message': 'Integration successful.', 'nst': array([  14,   14,   15, ..., 2293, 2294, 2294], dtype=int32), 'mused': array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)})
```